# Get all Jobs that have a date older than today's date and filter by user and the count of reviews per job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to fetch all Jobs that belong to current user that have a date older than today's date and I also need to also filter the jobs that have zero reviews.

I've tried the following:

```
Job.joins(:user, :review).where("jobs.date < ? AND jobs.status = ? AND users.id = ?", Time.now, 3 , user.id).group("jobs.id").having("COUNT(reviews) = ?", 0)
```

In case of a specific user id (3356) I should get one Job but I am getting none.

Here are my models

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :review
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_one :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`status` is an Enum (which needs to be 3, which is 'accepted')

What am I doing wrong? I'm not sure how to structure the SQL properly, so that's probably the issue. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I like to think about problems like this is breaking them down into smaller problems.

From your question, we want to...

Fetch all Jobs that:

- have an 'accepted' status

```rb
Job.accepted
```

- belong to current user

```rb
Job.where(user: current_user)
```

- have a date older than today's date

```rb
Job.where('date < ?', Time.zone.today)
```

- that have zero reviews

```rb
reviews = Review.all
Job.where.not(id: reviews.select(:job_id))
```

This one is a little different than the others and uses a [subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html).

---

Now, let's put all of that together and define a method in our Job class:

```rb
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [:other_status, :accepted]
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :review

  def self.unreviewed(user)
    accepted
      .where(user: user)
      .where('date < ?', Time.zone.today)
      .where.not(id: Review.select(:job_id))
  end
end
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
irb(main):002:0> puts Job.unreviewed(user).to_sql
SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."status" = 0 AND "jobs"."user_id" = 1 AND (date < '2019-03-26') AND "jobs"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "reviews"."job_id" FROM "reviews")
```

You can also find [some specs testing this here](https://gist.github.com/scottbartell/502ca973c052953091a6f5c2c8e4ed38).

Comment: Sounds cool, I like the approach very much, however this query is not returning expected results. I have Job.accepted method `scope :accepted, -> { where(status: 1) }` and putting all that together returns 3 jobs however the previous solution returns 2 records which is expected.

Comment: @jedi what record gets returned that is unexpected?

Comment: jobs that are accepted, belong to the user, older than today's date BUT both that DON't have a review and DO HAVE a review. One of them has a review.

Comment: So one Job that is being returned has a Review? If you look at that Review does it have a user_id for the given user?

Comment: Also, FYI, if you're using [`ActiveRecord::Enum`s](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) you get scopes based on the allowed values of the enum field for free. So, in my example above, the `enum status: [:other_status, :accepted]` automatically provides the `Job.other_status` and `Job.accepted` scopes.

Comment: Bartel, no, this Review doesn't have a user_id. And thanx for the Job.accepted based on Enum. I didn't realize it.

Comment: @jedi Ah, looks like I misunderstood the data model. I thought that a `Review` would have the same `user_id` as the `Job` that is being reviewed. But I can see how that doesn't make much sense. I updated my answer to account for this (`user.reviews.select(:job_id)` became `Review.select(:job_id)`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to do left outer joins instead of inner joins, if you do inner  join it won't take job if it has 0 reviews job must have at least one review then only it will take job's record, besides in left outer join, it will take all jobs record whether it has review or not.

```
Job.left_outer_joins(:user, :reviews).where("jobs.date < ? AND jobs.status = ? AND users.id = ?", Time.now, 3 , user.id).group("jobs.id").having("COUNT(reviews) = ?", 0)
```

Comment: Oh, I remember now how left joins works, thanx for that :)

Answer (score 1):

joins(:review) would do a inner join of Job and Review which would result in jobs with 0 reviews being skipped from the result. 
Try this:

```
Job.joins(:user).joins("left join reviews on reviews.job_id = jobs.id ").where("jobs.date < ? AND jobs.status = ? AND users.id = ?", Time.now, 3 , user.id).group("jobs.id").having("COUNT(reviews) = ?", 0)
```

Comment: OK, it works, it returns one Job, which what I expected. Great! What I missed is that I didn't think my query skipped jobs with 0 results. I would appreciate how LEFT JOIN works in this case and how it solved the problem.